# C# , splitting parts unclear

Tags: c#

I have seen some topics about this already but those we're a bit unclear about what I want,

Im making a Special WebBrowser in C#

But, I want to split the TextBox text

Like:

Textbox1.Text = "**http://google.com/lol**";

I want,

Label1.Text = "**http://google.com**";

And

Label2.Text = "**/lol**";

But i want it to like detect the URL from TextBox1.Text not just google.com, every url

**Like:**

**[**

Label1.Text = Label1.Text("ignorefrom/");
Label2.Text = Label2.Text("ignorefromno/");

**]**

Ofcourse the ting above isnt possible, but thats basicly what I mean

Anny1 know how I can do that

Possible better explaining.

I'm making a web browser I want to detect the

URL: for example: **http://google.com/lol**

I want the first and second part from an url in a label

So: **http://google.c om** in **label1** and **/lol** in **label2** with every url

I have seen multiple topics about this but this was a bit different then my case

Comment: What about a string like http://example.com/lol/lol? How do you split it then?

Comment: I hate to say it, but if you're having difficulty working out how to split up a URL then you're going to have an even tougher job writing a web browser.

Comment: Well, just with the first / i guess?

Comment: I just need to get the http://google.com and everything after it splitted: /whatevery/whatever

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the documentation for the [.NET class Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has the functionality you're looking for.

Example:

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/some/path/file.aspx");
Console.WriteLine(url.Host); // prints www.google.com
Console.WriteLine(url.AbsolutePath); // prints /some/path/file.aspx
```

Properties used in this example:

- [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'd suggest some example code (even if it's only a couple of lines); link-only answers are generally frowned upon and you may find your answer removed.

Comment: Hey, eemh im sorry for giving too less info but im using the FORMS

For examepl, i mean like:
TextBox1.Text = "http://google.com/somthing";
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com" + "somthing here" + "/somthing");

Comment: @Kylian105 You don't have to write the results to the console. You can assign these properties to your label's text property.

Comment: i edited the above reply i want to put somthing like between the URL so im not really sure how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to make changes to the URL?

Comment: Yeah, kinda
URL: http://google.nl/somthing
for example: WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com" + somthingelse + "/somthing");

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example to work with? Why do you want to change the URI?

Answer (score 0):

This should give the result you want:

```
using System.Uri;

Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com/lol");
Label1.Text = uri.AbsoluteUri;
Label2.Text = uri.PathAndQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the right tool, in this case you could use [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string url = "http://google.com/lol";
Uri uri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    Textbox1.Text = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host; 
    Label1.Text = uri.AbsolutePath;                              
}
```

If you want to include the query as mentioned in a comment you should use `uri.PathAndQuery`. Then `"http://google.com/lol?lol=1"` returns `/lol?lol=1` as desired.

Comment: This works like a charm :DDD, but one problem, if i did like: http://google.com/lol?lol=1 it removes to ?lol=1 :O?

Comment: @Kylian105: i have edited my answer, if you want to include the query you have to use `uri.PathAndQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Tim Schmelter

```
string url = "http://google.com/lol";
Uri uri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    Textbox1.Text = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host; 
    Label1.Text = uri.AbsolutePath;                              
}
```

works like a charm :)